# HazelCast, Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and CDI/Weld Serialization class not found error?

Tags: jsf, session, glassfish, cdi, hazelcast

I am testing HazelCast 3.1.3 and its HTTP Session Clustering/WM.    My target applications is a JSF 2.1/PrimeFaces  app and it makes heavy use of CDI.

It has a some javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped beans in it, among many other things.

I have written a simple WAR matching this and it uses very simple SessionScoped Bean.   I have configured HC/WM following the HC directions here: http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#HttpSessionClustering

Note:  I am not running an embedded HC; but rather configured WM to be client to an already running HC 'server' instance.    So far I have my single GF instance and the HC sever running on same box for this test.

This sorta works, in the WM/HC connects and creates sessions and stuff.   HC Server sees and accepts the WM client connects.

However, once more interesting stuff (interactions with SessionScoped objects in web app)  starts to happen HC/WM starts tossing ClassNotFound exceptions.   In particular CNF's for org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator.

I think this is because CDI in GF 3.1.2.2 is provided by a WELD OSGI 'thing' and that gets loaded by a lower level class loader that is 'closer' to the session manager within GF.  However, when WM/HC filter (loaded by the WAR classloader) visits the CDI/WELD proxied or wrapped session object to serialize it -- it cannot see the WELD classes (I have verified that ConversationIdGenerator is serializable).

Does anybody have any ideas on how to work around this issue?

I suppose delivering weld in my WAR may work or making WELD available in the common class loader may work -- but that is sub-optimal.

Hmm...Will this be a endemic problem with CDI provided as a service by an App container but then the session clustering provided as an application-level facet?   (or Will this sort of issue happen in WildFly/other too?)